# How to create time series with lagged in R

Tags: time-series, r

Would anyone else advise me, how to create time series with lagged in R.
I would the result is the difference with lagged, there is a function Delt() but the result is the percentage change. Please advise how to do that. Thank you

```
getSymbols("^GSPC")
DeltLagGSPC<-Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1:5)
```

update

I would calculate the computed result with the successive difference. The output format of Delt() is same as I expected, but the result is the percentage change with lagged. I would calculate the difference with lagged. Is there any function, same parameters as Delt() but calculate the difference change.

Comment: did you have a look at the function "lag" ? Furthermore this is at most a question for stackoverflow ...

Comment: That, or implement shift or get it from `data.table`. You can do a few things but I agree it doesn't fit here. On StackOverflow it would be a duplicate, so closing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on StackOverflow where it would be a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Look at the function "lag" and if you want a lag function that does not depend on some time series structure of the object then you can use this one:

```
shift<-function(x,shift_by){
  stopifnot(is.numeric(shift_by))
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x))

  if (length(shift_by)>1)
    return(sapply(shift_by,shift, x=x))

  out<-NULL
  abs_shift_by=abs(shift_by)
  if (shift_by > 0 )
    out<-c(tail(x,-abs_shift_by),rep(NA,abs_shift_by))
  else if (shift_by < 0 )
    out<-c(rep(NA,abs_shift_by), head(x,-abs_shift_by))
  else
    out<-x
  out
}
```

I prefer it in the meanwhile. It was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28432599/lag-in-r-vector-dataframe).